# ObservableField or LiveData? Which one is the best?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

I have been testing Livedata and AAC in general.

What is the core difference between LiveData and ObservableField?

Which one is the best and when should I use one over another?

Comment: You can find some answers here in the documentation of these objects. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableField

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The core difference is that `ObservableField<T>` is not lifecycle-aware and hence there cannot be any automatic subscription management. While `LiveData<T>` is lifecycle-aware and solves tons of headaches with subscription management when it comes to `Activity/Fragment` lifecycles.

There is no one way to answer what is the best to use. It is a personal choice, but I would suggest using `LiveData<T>` just to save yourself some time and avoid potential issues in the future.

Comment: What if I have a view model with a value that is only modified by user action on the view (through data binding)? Is there still any benefit to using LiveData when there is no data subscription involved?

Comment: @cambunctious In that case there are no benefits while using `LiveData`. BUT when we use `ViewModel` classes it usually mean that we are also following `MVVM` design principles, which state that there should be as little logic in your `View` as possible and that `ViewModel` should control its `View` and its state/data. So in that case `LiveData` would help but is not a 
necessity. If I were you, I would not use `LiveData` in this case even tho you are probably following `MVVM`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm not sure if I understand. In what way would LiveData "help" that ObservableField cannot for my case?

Comment: @cambunctious `LiveData` would help `ViewModel` to better control its `View` by prevent memory leaks, crashes due to stopped activity and to keep fresh data on configuration (orientation) changes. And that just fulfills `MVVM` better then `ObservableField ` without extra work. But as I said its not necessary to use `LiveData` if you are willing to handle mentioned cases yourself.

Comment: From a post by the Android developer team: "LiveData is lifecycle-aware but this is not a huge advantage with respect to Observable Fields because Data Binding already checks when the view is active"

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/android-data-binding-library-from-observable-fields-to-livedata-in-two-steps-690a384218f2#:~:text=is%20lifecycle-aware%20but%20this%20is%20not%20a%20huge%20advantage%20with%20respect%20to%20Observable%20Fields%20because%20Data%20Binding%20already%20checks%20when%20the%20view%20is%20active

Comment: @FlorianWalther Years later, thank you for this link. I basically went all the way backwards today trying to implement 2-way binding with manual Bindable Attribute fields in the viewmodel thanks to the Android Docs. It seems for 2-way they'd prefer if you use JetPack Compose (which is not for everyone, yet). I'm going to stick with a LiveData approach to 2-way binding without worrying if I'm regressing now.

Answer (score 7):

Both `LiveData` and `Observable` could be used alternatively. `LiveData` is lifecycle aware and hence will notify only the observables which are "active".

Quoting official documentation on https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/architecture#livedata

> Unlike objects that implement Observable—such as observable fields—LiveData objects know about the lifecycle of the observers subscribed to the data changes. This knowledge enables many benefits, which are explained in The advantages of using LiveData. In Android Studio version 3.1 and higher, you can replace observable fields with LiveData objects in your data binding code.

As mentioned both are usable for UI binding interchangeably. `LiveData` is a quick method but if you want more control on the binding `Obserable` is a way to go with.

Quoting official documentation on https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/architecture#observable-viewmodel

> There are situations where you might prefer to use a ViewModel component that implements the Observable interface over using LiveData objects, even if you lose the lifecycle management capabilities of LiveData. Using a ViewModel component that implements Observable gives you more control over the binding adapters in your app. For example, this pattern gives you more control over the notifications when data changes, it also allows you to specify a custom method to set the value of an attribute in two-way data binding.

We get options to customize the binding in case of an `Observable` which might be helpful in some case.

**Personal preference is to go with `LiveData`. In case some some customization or more control is needed on the binding go for `Obervable`**

Comment: "For example, this pattern gives you more control over the notifications when data changes, it also allows you to specify a custom method to set the value of an attribute in two-way data binding." I thought you could override the setValue method on MutableLiveData to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 3):

**Similarities**

- Work well with data binding
- Bound views automatically unsubscribe when in the background
- POJO classes can also subscribe to changes

**Differences**

- `LiveData` allows for POJO subscribers to be lifecycle aware. Meaning that if you have a property B that you want to update when A changes, you can opt to not receive updates when the attached view is inactive. This saves resources.
- Background thread updates of `ObservableField<T>` are immediate. `MutableLiveData.postData` is delayed.
- Values of `LiveData<T>` and `ObservableField<T>` are always nullable, but the primitive implementations `ObservableInt`, `-Float`, `-Boolean` etc are non-nullable.
- `MutableLiveData<T>` doesn't take a constructor value to set on initialization.

**When to use what**

- Do you have external events that may trigger cascading data change in the ViewModel when the app is in the backgrond? You should probably go for `LiveData`
- Do you require value update on background threads to be immediate*? Use Observables

None of the above requirements? You can't go wrong with either but `ObservableField` is a simpler class.

*) "Immediate" in the sense that a `get` directly after a `set/postValue` is guaranteed to return the value you just set. None of the types are of course immediate when it comes to UI update.

Comment: I believe MutableLiveData now does take a constructor value for initialization

Comment: you mentioned :
Do you have external events that may trigger cascading data change in the ViewModel

can i write some code to simulate this and see how a crash happens with observable field as it is not lifecycle aware...